# Why is the water pressure so high from my overhead water tank?

Tags: plumbing, water, faucet, water-pressure

We have recently rented a house and it has normal taps fitte, and a normal 
overhead water tank, but the water pressure is very high. The water comes out 
with so much pressure, that if I am trying to rinse anything it makes 
water spray everywhere. What could be the reason?

Its a normal plastic 500 lt overhead tank, and it doesn't have a cap to close its top.  It is not sealed and pressurized. There are no pressure regulators, and there is no water heater in the system. It's just a fill and use kind of tank.

For water flow, a 1.5 in. pipe is fitted to its bottom. There is a check valve, and its turned full open. The tank is fitted on the 2nd floor (25ft above ground level). We fill the tank with bore \ well water with the help of an electric pump. When we open any tap, water pressure is very high.

What could be the reason?

Comment: You need to add a lot more detail.  Is it city water or well.  If it is a well, what kind?  (approximate well depth)  What type and size of pump is it?  Give us some more details and I would be happy to edit your question for proper English and remove the down-vote (and probably change it to an up-vote). :D

Comment: Overhead tank sounds like the OP is referring to a gravity fed system that's common in locations like India, where the municipal supply is irregular. Is the tank only gravity based, or is it sealed and pressurized? If it's pressurized, is there some kind of pressure regulator, is there a check valve, and is there a water heater in the system?

Comment: How is the water pressure *on* the second floor?

Comment: A 25 ft head of water will give about 12 psi of pressure. Your taps are not at ground level so pressure there will be less.

Answer (score 2):

You may need an aerator.  If it needs replacing, then the water may spatter a lot.  The aerator is the piece that screws into the end of the spigot.  It limits the flow of water to between 1.5 and 2.5 gallons per minute and entrains air into the water stream to prevent splashing.  From what you describe, it may even be missing.  You can pick one up at any hardware store.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer may depend on which country the house is in.

In the UK, houses typically have a high pressure water supply to a cold-water tank in the loft. Supply of cold water to taps is from this tank (and hence is low pressure).

However, I believe by UK law, the kitchen taps must be connected to the high-pressure supply as the kitchen tap is used to provide drinking water. Things can fall into a cold-water tank!

So your kitchen tap could be operating at high pressure even in a house with a cold water tank.

There is often a separate cold-water header tank for the heating system. So the presence of a small water tank does not necessarily mean that taps are connected to it.

In flats (apartment buildings) and in some modern houses, high-pressure systems are used.

In DIY stores you will see that tap packaging states whether the taps are suitable for high-pressure or low pressure.

Comment: @Kaz: True but I wrote my answer before that info was added to the question. :-(

Answer (score 1):

I realise that this is a rather old question - but you say that the pipe coming out of the tank is around 1.5 inches in diameter. I assume that the tap has a diameter of around .5 inch. If that is the case then you are getting such a high pressure (actually velocity rather than pressure)because of this reduction in pipe diameter.

Replace the 1.5 inch pipe with a smaller diameter pipe and you'll see the velocity drop.

Think of pinching a garden hose at the end to make the jet spray further.

Answer (score -1):

put ball valve in the discharge line and keep it open slightly. you will get desirable speed and discharge.